# Exec a UNIX command and if not works exec other without showing errors

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

I want to do: 
`foo || pwd`
So as `foo` command fails I need just to get the second output `pwd` but I dont want the line `No command 'foo' found, did you mean....`

How can I do it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect the STDERR output of `foo` to `/dev/null` so you don't see the errors.

```
foo 2>/dev/null || pwd
```

Comment: Note that the error message can be redirected because it comes from the `command_not_found_handle` hook which runs in place of the missing command, rather than from the shell that spawns the command.

Comment: Pedantically, the error message can be redirected merely because it's printed on stderr. It doesn't really matter which process produces it.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the standard error of the first command

```
foo 2> /dev/null || pwd
```